# How to replace the tabs at the beginning of a new line using regex?

Tags: java, regex

I'm using java to try to replace the four spaces at the beginning of a new line to a tab. I would like to do this using regular expressions. My issue is that the regex is currently replacing all four-space-sequences with a single tab. I want it to insert a tab for each four-space-sequence. Right now I have:

```
    public String translate(String text) {
        text = text.replaceAll("(?m)^(    )+", "\t");
        return text;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want the `+` because you want *exactly* 4 spaces, and you need a look-behind assertion:

```
text = text.replaceAll("(?m)(?<=^ *)    ", "\t");
```

Note: This should only be used for input of about 10K or less due to the backtracking required by the look behind. For larger input, use a pattern and matcher etc

Unlike the other answers, this one actually works (see test below), because it uses a positive look-behind `(?<=^ *)` to assert that only spaces are between the start of input and the target replacement, without which you'll only match the *first* 4 spaces:

```
String text = "        a\n        b    \n";
text = text.replaceAll("(?m)(?<=^ *)    ", "\t");
System.out.println(text.replace("\t", "TAB"));
```

Output:

```
TABTABa
TABTABb
```

Comment: Add the `for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {text += text;}` (text length will become 25k) and take your time waiting for it to finish. When you dive into regexes, you'll need to deal with backtracks, engine-specific feautures and so, which requires much insight to develop, debug, or even understand. Does one-liner worth it?

Comment: @FrozenSpider You are correct - this solution only works for modest sized input (10K or so) due to the backtracking issue.

Answer (score 2):

Is it really necessary to use regular expressions for that? If not, i suggest the following code. It will replace **every** 4-spaces sequence **at the line start** with a tab (i.e. one tab per sequence), and won't affect all other 4-spaces.

#### Unlike regular expressions, this code performs instantly even for large text block.

```
String text = "    4    spaces\n        four    more\n    \n text";
String[] split = text.split("\n");
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(text.length());
for (String string : split) {
    int idx = 0;
    while (true) {
        String temp = string.substring(idx);
        if (temp.startsWith("    ")) {
            // Append a tab and push actual start index further
            result.append('\t');
            idx = idx + 4;
        } else {
            result.append(temp);
            break;
        }
    }
    result.append('\n');
}
System.out.println(text);
System.out.println("====");
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: this seems unnecessarily complex

Comment: -1 normally I wouldn't downvote an answer for poor code, but this answer is *such* a bad solution it deserves 100 downvotes. Just because it "works" does't make it "good" - you can do this in one line!

Comment: @Bohemian Yes, you may, but IMO that's not the problem - you'll wrap it in a function anyway. However, what IS a problem, is a poor rexeg performance. Try increasing string size to 50k characters - my solution works instantly, while best regex submitted for now (i.e. yours) stops the world.

Comment: @ Frozen Spider: Hope you understand the difference between `exactly 4 spaces` and `1 or more spaces`. And your own answer, what to say.. I guess Bohemian made it quite clear what it deserves :)

Comment: @anubhava Indeed I do understand the difference, and in my opition, my code sample does exactly the thing. I do not agree, that regex-based answer is better, than mine - it's concise, yet impractical - but that's not up to me to decide. I hope this answer would be helpful at least to others.